# Display a variable in a div in google sheet sidebar

Tags: javascript, sidebar, google-sheets-api

I have a function in googlesheets code.gs; the function assigns value to a variable.

```
function assignVariable()
{
var name = "My Name"
}
```

and I have a span with id="var" in the sidebar.html

```
<span id="var"></span>
```

I want to display the variable "name" in the span with id="var". I tried getElementById and replace with innerHtml, it didn't work for me (the code below).

```
<span id="var" style="vertical-align: middle">
<script>
document.getElementById("var").innerHTML = name;
</script>
</span>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>

<span id="var"></span>

<script>
var name = "My Name"
document.getElementById("var").innerHTML = name;
</script>

</body>
```

or

```
<script>
function myFunction(name) {
var name = "my name"
    return name;
}
document.getElementById("var").innerHTML = myFunction(name);
</script>
```

you should try this if your value is hard coded.....

Comment: I want to a variable to be displayed into the sidebar. The variable has to be assigned by a function in the code.gs file. Any kind of working code will do for me. I can tweak around it and use it for my need. Currently, the calling a function in the getElementById method does not return the value.

Answer (score -1):

It will not work.

**Reason?**

Because the variable `name` is local to the `function`. It is unavailable for the outside world.

```
function assignVariable()
{
    // local scope..
    var name = "My Name";
}

name; // undefined... :(
```

I would not advise you to create a global variable but i do not actually know why do you want to print it as such so with that note, you need to return the result from the function or modify its scope.

There are plenty of ways to achieve this. One of them is,

```
function assignVariable()
{
    var name = "My Name";
    return name;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span id="var" style="vertical-align: middle"></span>
<script>
    document.getElementById("var").innerHTML = assignVariable();
</script>
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/lukima/edit?html,output)**

Comment: I copied and pasted your codes; it is not working. It is giving me a blank span.

Comment: Your code is fine, but it is not taking the values from the function assignVariable();. Instead, I am getting a blank span. Any kind of working code to pull any data from code.gs into sidebar HTML would work for me. I can tweak around and modify the code to meet my needs.

Comment: I have updated my answer with working DEMO. Check the css and other neighbour code. It must be something else going on.

Comment: Also, notice that i have included the script below the `span`. This is because otherwise span was not available for script to manipulate. This is where document ready comes handy. **Recommended:** keep your scripts after the HTML body content.

Comment: Okay, that works on your Working Demo; so that should have worked on the google sheets and sidebar as well, but it DIDN'T. That's the problem. I want to display that value on a sidebar on a google sheet. I put the JS code on code.gs and then I put the HTML on the sidebar HTML code, and it does not take the value from the function. Sorry about it. If you can do the same on a google sheet and try, may be you will understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you show the pieces of actual code. I can-not create the actual replica of what you are doing.

Comment: I created a test sheet and am sharing with you. Thanks for your effort already. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P3M0KwVhH6g4XPIhJI0Pcbl8Iq_653_pvjN7xkBk4JA/edit?usp=sharing